# Php regexp get the strings from array print_r like string

Tags: php, preg-match

Im trying to list out here how to match strings that looks like array printr.

```
variable_data[0][var_name]
```

I would like to get from above example 3 strings, variable_data, 0 and var_name.
That above example is saved in DB so i same structure of array could be recreated but im stuck. Also a if case should look up IF the string (as above) is in that structure, otherwise no preg_match is needed.

Note: i dont want to serialize that array since the array 'may' contain some characters that might break it when unserializing and i also need that value in the array to be fully visible.

Any one with regexp skills who might know the approach ?

***Solution:***

```
(\b([\w]*[\w]).\b([\w]*[\w]).+(\b[\w]*[\w]))
```

Thos 2 first indexes should be skipped... but i still get what i want :)

Answer (score 1):

Not for nothing but couldn't you just do..

```
$result = explode('[', someString);
foreach ($result as $i => $v) {
    $temp = str_replace(']'. ''. $result[$i]);
    //Do something with temp
}
```

Obviously you need to edit the above a little bit depending on what you are doing but it is very simple and even gives you the same flexibility and you don't need to invoke the matching engine...

I don't think we build regex's here for people... instead please see http://regexpal.com/ for a Regex tester / builder with visual aid.

Furthermore people usually don't know how to use them properly which is then fostered by others creating the expressions for them.

Please remember complex expressions can have terrible performance overheads although there is nothing seemingly complex about your request...

Then after it is compelte post your completed RegEx and answer your own question for maximum 1337ne$$ :)

But since I am nice here is your reward:

```
\[.+\]\[\d+\]
```

or

```
 [a-z]+_[a-z]+\[.+\]\[\d+\]
```

Depending on what you want to match out of the string (which you didn't specify) so I assumed all

Both perform as follows:

```
arr_var[name][0]; //Matched

arr_var[name]; //Not matched


arr_var[name][0][1];//Matched

arr_var[name][2220][11];//Matched
```

Again, test them and understand with visual aid at the above link.

Comment: Lol thanks :) I've always thought that matching with reg is faster and better for performance, but i could be totally wrong. I normally use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ for reg patterns but seems that AS3 and PHP a are not that similar in reg, what is used in AS3 didnt work as well in php

Comment: Of course, i will use the loop for now, could not get the patterns to work on my case. Im still trying to create something here, got this so far: (\w*[a-zA-Z0-9]) Problem is that this matches first group and then stops, need to get all 3 ones :S

Comment: What do you mean and then stops? the use of + or * allows more results than others... also I don't see any quantification on your capturing groups in your expression ... () notation is for groups. And you have that but For instance (\w*[a-zA-Z0-9])\1 matches the rr and 11 because \1 refers to the first match which is an optional boundry followed by a char which is followed by the char that matched. This implies that only ss or XX or repeating characters will be matched... did that help?

Comment: Hm.. i really suck at this :P maybe im getting this all wrong, thought "group" means that if one or more matches are found, they are returned as array. f.ex. $matches = array(); if( preg_match('/(\w*[a-zA-Z0-9])/', 'variable_data[0][var_name]',$matches)){ echo '<pre>'; print_r($matches); echo '</pre>'; } would return $matches[0] as 'variable_data', $matches[1] as '0' and $matches[2] as 'var_name'

Comment: solved it: (\b([\w]*[\w]).\b([\w]*[\w]).+(\b[\w]*[\w])) tho 2 first indexes are not interesing, but i still get the rest of them as i need.

Answer (score 1):

***Solution:***

```
(\b([\w]*[\w]).\b([\w]*[\w]).+(\b[\w]*[\w]))
```

Those 2 first indexes should be skipped... but i still get what i want :)

***Edit***

Here is improved one:

```
$str = "variable[group1][parent][child][grandchild]";
preg_match_all('/(\b([\w]*[\w]))/', $str,$matches);
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';

// Output
Array  
        (  
            [0] => variable  
            [1] => group1  
            [2] => parent  
            [3] => child  
            [4] => grandchild  
        )
```